# How do I get Dialog instance from View class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to dismiss dialog from button click so I am trying to get Instance of Dialog from the `View` Class, then dismiss it.

Though I could declare the `AlertDialog` ahead of the call to dismiss, then call the `AlertDialog` to dismiss, but is there a way I can do the following:

```
 re_new_code.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((AlertDialog)v).dismiss(); //How can I do something like this?
        }
    });
```

Comment: No you cannot do this. You will need to create global instance of `AlertDialog` and then dismiss the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a prop of AlertDialog and show it the OnCreate method. when you do that you can dismiss alert dialog everywhere you want.